# Android Rss Feed (open inside an app not in a browser)

Tags: java, android, rss

I have a question about my rss feed. My rss feed is working just fine, but it opens the feed in an Android Browser. I am wondering is there a way to open it inside an app not in a browser? (if it opens in a browser, there is no point for me to build this)

This is the lines I believe it opens in a browser

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
    RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getLink());


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You Have to create New Activity to receive RSS feed

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)arg1;
            TextView textView = (TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.eBooksTitle);
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EbookDescriptionActivity.class)
            .putExtra("link_to_load", textView.getTag().toString()));
}
```

in EbookDescriptionActivity.class you can receive the link and handle it in your layout

```
        String web_link;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.ebooks_details_activity);

            web_link = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link_to_load");
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am just curious that what is eBooksTitle and ebooks_details_activity, where did you define it? For the EbookDescriptionActivity and onItemClick class, do I just copy that code? 

It also said that MainActivity.this is No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope. How do I fix that?

Comment: dont just copy and paste that code you have to understand.. MainActivity is present class  and EBookDescriptionActivity is next class or activity in which you have to show your data ebookTitle is a textview from where i want to get link..